# Exporting a module containing a mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**This is the module part :**
    doc/docRdv

```
module.exports = function (mongooseRdv){
   var RdvSchema = new Schema({
     Date: {type: Date},
   });

   var models ={
     Rdv : mongoose.model('Rdv',RdvSchema)
   };

   return models;
}
```

**This is the main.js:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/DocTest');

var docRdv = require('./doc/docRdv');

var Rdv1 = new models.Rdv({
   Date: new Date
});
```

**I'm getting the following error:**

```
ReferenceError: models is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (c:\DOCFLEET\Test\main.js:5:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Timeout.Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:604:10)
at ontimeout (timers.js:386:14)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
```

**Anyone as an idea on how to fix it?**

Comment: Why do you need a function there? Just declare a function content inside a module and return `models`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are exporting a function that create the `models` and not the `models` themselves.

Either use `new docRdv().Rdv(...)` in `main`

Or execute the function and export the result

```
module.exports = (function (mongooseRdv){
   var RdvSchema = new Schema({
     Date: {type: Date},
   });

   var models ={
     Rdv : mongoose.model('Rdv',RdvSchema)
   };

   return models;
})();
```